# Modern POD to HTML converter to produce results like search.cpan.org

Tags: perl

Is there code available to convert POD to HTML in a similar manner as search.cpan.org? I'd like to run it over my CPAN distribution modules to see how they'll look before releasing.

The pod2html that comes with Perl seems rather outdated. It does quaint things like depositing temporary files in the current directory and creating links like "the so-and-so manpage", and the output is far inferior to the beautiful output of search.cpan.org. But not sure what other people are using.

Comment: Actually, beauty is just a matter of building a stylesheet.

Comment: If only the code used to run cpan.org was open source... sigh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote [pod2cpanhtml](https://metacpan.org/source/JMCNAMARA/App-Pod2CpanHtml-0.04/bin/pod2cpanhtml) for exactly the reasons you describe.

It is only a tiny piece of code that makes use of [Pod::Simple::HTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aSimple%3a%3aHTML) and the [search.cpan.org CSS](http://search.cpan.org/s/style.css) but I find it very useful.

Answer (score 12):

Before I upload to CPAN, I check my POD by looking at it in a browser from http://search.cpan.org/pod2html.

Form there, I click on `Browse...`

I navigate to the directory containing my code and double-click on the `.pm` file.

Then click on `Submit Query`.

It's the closest I've seen to the real thing.

See also [pod2cpanhtml.](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pod2cpanhtml)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to mob's suggestions, I was quite happy with [Pod::ProjectDocs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aProjectDocs). It needed few minor tweaks, but it looks more or less like CPAN.

Comment: Actually this is a nice discovery since looks like a cool and easy way of pulling together all of the supporting documents for a project with a nice main page.  Thanks for mentioning this tool.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=346174), the trick is to use [`Pod::HtmlEasy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aHtmlEasy). Or maybe the trick is to use [`Apache::Pod::HTML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache%3a%3aPod%3a%3aHTML). Or [`Pod::Tree`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aTree)? I don't know, but there are a few suggestions there.